# How do I remove all the tags at once from the Finder sidebar?

Tags: finder, finder-tag, sidebar

I have nearly 1,500 tags. Somehow, they are all marked to appear in the sidebar. My MacBook Pro is 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7 with 16GB of memory, but it still takes 7 seconds for Finder to remove just one of them via Finder Preferences. **Is there anyway to remove all of the tags from the sidebar using Terminal or by some other means?** I do not want to delete them, just remove them from the sidebar. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To remove all **Tags** at once, from the **Sidebar** in **Finder**, uncheck **Recent Tags** under **Tags** in the **Sidebar** preferences in **Finder**:

**Finder** > **Preferences...** > **Sidebar** > **Tags** > *uncheck* **Recent Tags**

This stops **Tags** from appearing in the **Sidebar** in **Finder** without deleting the **Tags** that have been set.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had not seen that option. The problem is that I wanted about a dozen tags to appear but not all 1470 tags. That meant unchecking the other 1400+ tags one by one. (I'm not sure how they all got checked in the first place!) Anyway, I set up a loop in Keyboard Maestro. It eventually finished the job.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, put the cursor on the Tags heading in the sidebar. To the right of this the word Hide should appear. Just click Hide.